# error not hiding on touch listener, click listener : Android

Tags: android

I have a Android program with few text box. I set error when value is null. 
I want on touch the error should disappear and keyboard to be shown. but error is shown. but not hidden when I touch or click.

```
else if(txtLdays.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
 {
     txtLdays.requestFocus();   
     txtLdays.setError("Please Enter Number of Days " );  
    // delay();

     return false;
 }
```

and my edit text functions I call on oncreate

```
        txtLdays = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLdays);
        txtLdays.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        txtLdays.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
        txtLdays.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
        txtLdays.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789."));
        txtLdays.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);

        txtLdays.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(5,1)});

txtLdays.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {                                                       
                 // your code here....
                txtLdays.setError(null);      

                 return false;
            }
        });
        txtLdays.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                     txtLdays.requestFocus();   
                    txtLdays.setError(null); 
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

NOT Sure what the problem but you can use like

```
else if(txtLdays.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
             {

                 txtLdays.requestFocus();   
                 txtLdays.setError("Please Enter Number of Days " );  
                // delay();

                 return false;
             }
```

**AND ANOTHER OPTION**

use TextWatcher

```
 txtLdays.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    //Validation.hasText(txtLdays);
                                     your conditions here 
                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                        int count) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: I mean the error is coming but when i click again the error is not hiding i.e not setting null

Comment: then in else part add setError(null); but if you use TextWatcher's it will solve the problem

Comment: i hav used this also ,  text watcher works when the keyboard is shown . even the keyboard is not popping when i touch

Comment: i updated the TextWatcher's code.. check it.. Hope it will solve

Comment: ya i did that already. still m not getting the keyboard i.e 12 key keyboard

Comment: I hope that you are using some form right ? if yes buy clicking submit button just call a function which will have all validations... then each click you can check it again..  https://sites.google.com/site/khetiyachintan/sample-example/edit-text-validation-example ... check it once

Comment: yeah i have that... i have a huge validation function this was just a small part of it..

Comment: the problem is the keyBoard not showing up as expected... i have to 5-6 times to open the keyboard

Comment: hmm...that's my mistake i understand wrongly... i hope if no value you are adding error... i think upto this is correct.. then?.. if you click that error you want to show keyboard or by clicking field itself ?? here i am getting a problem

Comment: Yup u got it correct now. sorry my question was not up to the mark.. sry it took u time to understand

Comment: so check the functions may deprecated... I think in 4.0 we can use... InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
           Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
     //imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchButton.getWindowToken(), 0);
     imm.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(searchButton.getWindowToken(), 0);

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your error when your EditText receives focus

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            editText.setError(null);
        } 
    }
});
```